# What is a specific word to describe necessary products that customers buy infrequently?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, vocabulary

Such as a car, microwave oven, espresso machine, electric kettle, television, etc.

Comment: *espresso machine?* ***necessary**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I remember the living, daily horror that I went through before I bought an espresso machine. Can any society truly call itself civilized when it has people who don't have espresso machines?

Comment: @Jay: When I were a lad, we only had *instant* coffee! (and that was made with mud and ground-up acorns! :) But don't get me started - Back in the day, I was right there with Dilbert: [You had *zeros?* We had to use the letter "O"](http://dilbert.com/strip/1992-09-08)

Comment: @Jay, yes it can, if those without an espresso machine can choose from half a dozen cafés within a five-minute walk from home.

Comment: @Drew Staple goods are "[bought often and consumed routinely](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/staple-goods-staples.html)" - So things like bread, milk, and eggs would count as "staples", but cars, microwaves, and televisions would normally not.

Comment: In economics, such products are considered *inelastic*. They are "must haves". They usually include not what you have mentioned, but food, shelter, utilities, etc.

Comment: Your question is a bit of a contradiction in terms. If products are necessary, you buy them, if you can, as often as you need to buy them them.

Comment: Apart from the car, we'd call all of those "appliances" , or "consumer electrics/electronics". Narrow the focus to cookers, microwaves, washers, fridges, and the like, and they're "white goods".

Comment: @RichardKayser there's no contradiction. They are talking about things with long service lives. You can argue about how necessary they are, but buying "as often as you need to buy them" can easily be "once every 10 years (or longer)" for a car, TV, etc.

Comment: It's all relative. Of course an espresso machine is not a necessity, not like, say, a pizza oven.

Comment: @ChrisH That's exactly what I'm objecting to, the OP's use of the word *necessary*. There are too many people in the world who would join me in  considering that a joke. It's a poorly posed question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In *British* English, they're

> **consumer durables**
>    *Manufactured items, typically cars **or household appliances**, that are expected to have a relatively long useful life after purchase.* [(Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consumer_durables)

Sometimes they're called ***durable goods***, or just ***durables*** (*durable* being defined as *able to withstand wear, pressure, or damage; hard-wearing*).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @D41V30N you could mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: I think this is right. In American English, "durable goods" would probably be the more common phrase.

Comment: Not the same thing, but related product classification: [hard goods and soft goods](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/070715/what-do-hard-and-soft-goods-retail-sector-refer.asp) – hard goods are sometimes synonymous to [durables](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/durables.asp)

Comment: Actually, all of the forms mentioned in this answer are reasonably common in American English, particularly in the context of economics.

Comment: A five pound box of salt will last a long time.

Comment: Yes.  Although I'm surprised to see that most definitions of the phrase include cars.  I've always thought of consumer durables as items you use in and around the house premises (i.e. excluding cars).

Comment: @JohnY Seconded; I've definitely heard all of these terms in American English, but "consumer durables", "durable goods", and "durables" mostly in the literature or journalism of economics.

Comment: I've literally heard no variant of this in the UK.

Comment: @AJFaraday: This particular class of "things people spend money on" was far more important in the first few decades after WW2, because they reflected both *economic output* and *standard of living*. But advanced economies are more "service-oriented" today. We spend more on entertainment, eating out, travel, etc. (plus we often upgrade things like phones and computers long before they "wear out"), so we simply don't have so much reason to refer to ***consumer durables*** and variations thereof.

Comment: ...see [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=durable+goods%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cconsumer+durables%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cdurable+goods%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cconsumer+durables%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdurable%20goods%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsumer%20durables%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdurable%20goods%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconsumer%20durables%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), which shows the US/UK split (such as it is), *and* the across-the-board decline over recent decades.

Answer (score 2):

***[Consumer discretionary goods](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/consumer-discretionary.asp)***:

> - goods and services that are considered non-essential by consumers, but desirable if their available income is sufficient to purchase them. ***They include durable goods, apparel, entertainment and leisure, and automobiles.***  The purchase of consumer discretionary goods is also influenced by the state of the economy, which can affect consumer confidence.

(www.investopedia.com)

Comment: "Necessary" (from the question title) and "non-essential" (in your answer) seem to conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I seriously doubt an espresso machine can be considered as necessary unless you own a coffee shop.  That being said, a necessary item can be termed "necessity," while any product that can be bought to satisfy wants and/or needs would be a "commodity."  In economics the term "necessity goods" is used to describe those items we cannot live without.

Answer (score 0):

Durable sales are a good indication of an impending economic downturn. When there is uncertainty, folks tend to hold off on replacing the durable goods in the household. This also includes vehicles.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This doesn't appear to directly answer the question. Please keep the answer box for Answers only. This appears to be a comment on FumbleFinger's answer; once you have gained more rep (by asking and answering questions) you'll be able to post comments.